# Using Bitbucket environment variables in python code

Tags: python, boto3, bitbucket-pipelines

I have set Environment variables in Bitbucket namely 'GIT_USERNAME' and 'GIT_PASSWORD' with the respective credentials at the repository level. However, when I issue a git pull, the code is not picking the variable values. I have a simple pipeline setup to pull the code onto my EC2 instance using SSM.

```
import boto3
ssm = boto3.client('ssm' )    
testCommand = ssm.send_command( InstanceIds=[ 'i-***********' ], 
                                DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript', 
                                Parameters={ "commands":[ "cd /home/ec2-user; sudo git pull https://$GIT_USERNAME:$GIT_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/master-path" ]  } )
```

How can I make these variables work, please suggest